# Calculate the total on events with two time conditions

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery that looks something like this:

```
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('timestamp', 'TIMESTAMP', mode='REQUIRED', description='Data point timestamp'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('event_id', 'STRING', description='EventID'),
        [...]
    ]
```

The table has a fairly large dataset, and I'm trying to find write an efficient query that returns the number of events that happened in the last 24 hours *but also* within the last N days. That is, two different records with different conditions but the same `event_id`. I don't care so much about the actual `event_id`, but rather the distribution.

Ideally, the query would return something like this:

```
7_days: 20
30_days: 15
60_days: 7
```

If it's impossible to do this in pure SQL, I also have Pandas available at my disposal.

Comment: Does BigQuery not support the UNION operation?

Comment: Yes it does, @mustaccio: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union

Comment: There's your answer then.

Comment: Will need to do some reading, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mustaccio's pointer above. Here's how I managed to get it to work using `INTERSECT DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    event_id
  FROM
    `foo.bar.blah`
  WHERE
    DATE(timestamp) = current_date()

  INTERSECT DISTINCT

  SELECT DISTINCT
    event_id
  FROM
    `foo.bar.blah`
  WHERE
    (DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
)
```

The two dates in the last `SELECT` needs to be adjusted according to the criterion of course.